# How to plug logic into session invalidation due to cookie expiration

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

In my app, I want to send some request to the api on session invalidation.

I want to be able to differentiate when a user logs out (clicks on the button), and when he is automatically logged out (eg, after inactivity period, cookie expiration...)

I think I've managed most of the use cases, the only remaining one is to be able to 'plug' some logic when the cookie expires, but before the session is cleaned-up.

Comment: When the user clicks a button, you call session#invalidate yourself. You can place your logic there or override session#invalidate.

Comment: @Gaurav Thank you, I think I should edit my question. After thinking a bit more, my exact use case here is I want to 'plug' some logic at cookie expiration time, but before ember-simple-auth has cleared the session.